# Determine if specific Drive letter is available via batch file

Tags: batch-file, flash, usb

We use batch files to back up files or folders to external Media (such as a flash drive, or Rewritable CD-ROM or DVR disk). I will start with USB flash drive.

We set the desired drive letter in our startup so it's part of the environment: Set ZDRIVE1=F

So, want to be able to check if %ZDRIVE1%: is available, and if not, prompt user to insert the flash drive, retest, them move to the part where we start copying files to the designated flash drive.

We had a utility called dskquery that  basically did this, but no one can find the source so we can recompile for 32/64 bit compatibility.

Comment: `wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" get name /value` will give you a list of attached flash drives.  Change that to `where "drivetype=2 or drivetype=5"` to include CD-ROM drives.  I'm not aware of any simple way to determine whether there's a writable CD installed in the drive though.  If you want a more thorough answer, you should edit your question and post the code you've written, explaining what you're having problems with.

Comment: @rojo That is not foolproof. I have a removable USB drive that reports itself as drivetype 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
Set "ZDRIVE1=F"
:test
pushd %ZDRIVE1%:
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (
echo the drive is aviable.
pause
goto :eof
) else (
echo please insert the flash drive.
pause
)
goto test
```

replace `goto :eof` on line 8 with `goto yourlabel`
also the drive of a USB flash drive can be `G:`,`H:` and so on, not necessary `F:` ...

Comment: Why not just use an `IF EXIST` instead. I would put a popd in their as well when it is successful.